# The name 'InitializeComponent()' does not exist in the current context (c#, emgucv)

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, emgucv

I am trying to run this code using c# and emgucv to draw a histogram for an image but it keeps giving me an error that 'The name   'InitializeComponent()' does not exist in the current context'. I tried to add references but it is not working.

```
using ZedGraph;
using System;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Xaml;
using System.Xml;
;



namespace My_EMGU_Program
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
        float[] BlueHist;
        float[] GreenHist;
        float[] RedHist;
        DenseHistogram Histo = new DenseHistogram(255, new RangeF(0, 255));
        Image<Gray, Byte> img2Blue = img[0];
        Image<Gray, Byte> img2Green = img[1];
        Image<Gray, Byte> img2Red = img[2];

        Histo.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img2Blue }, true, null);
        //The data is here
        //Histo.MatND.ManagedArray
        BlueHist = new float[256];
        Histo.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(BlueHist, 0);

        Histo.Clear();

        Histo.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img2Green }, true, null);
        GreenHist = new float[256];
        Histo.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(GreenHist, 0);

        Histo.Clear();

        Histo.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img2Red }, true, null);
        RedHist = new float[256];
        Histo.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(RedHist, 0);

        float[] GrayHist;

        Image<Gray, Byte> img_gray = new Image<Gray, byte>                (Openfile.FileName);

        Histo.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img_gray }, true, null);
        //The data is here
        //Histo.MatND.ManagedArray
        GrayHist = new float[256];
        Histo.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(GrayHist, 0);


        /*This Methof call will produced the Histograms for you*/
        Add_Histogram(GrayHist, "Gray Histogram");
        Add_Histogram(BlueHist, "Blue Histogram");
        Add_Histogram(GreenHist, "Green Histogram");
        Add_Histogram(RedHist, "Red Histogram");
      }
    }

    /* You can extend this method to set line colour x and y  titles quite easily */
    //Global X Y locations to stack Histograms
    int X = 10, Y = 10;
    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    void Add_Histogram(float[] Histo_dat, string Histo_Title = "Histogram Title")
    {

      //Create the Control
      ZedGraphControl zgc = new ZedGraphControl();
      zgc.Location = new Point(Y, X);
      zgc.Size = new Size(panel1.Width - 20, 200);
      X += (zgc.Size.Height + 20); //increas X for next Graph

      GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;

      myPane.Title.Text = Histo_Title;
      myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "X Axis - Pixel Bin Values";
      myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Y Axis - Total Number of Pixels";

      //Create an array that Zedgraph can use
      PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();
      for (int i = 0; i < Histo_dat.Length; i++)
      {
        list1.Add(new PointPair(i, Histo_dat[i]));
      }

      //Add the data to the control
      LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Title", list1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.Circle);
      zgc.AxisChange();

      //Add the controll and refresh form
      panel1.Controls.Add(zgc);
      this.Refresh();


    }

    //In case you wish to restart and draw newly calculated histograms
    void Clear_Histograms()
    {

      panel1.Controls.Clear();
      X = 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Form1` is a partial class.
Which means there is another file Form1.designer.cs that contains the missing method.
You can't just copy and paste that code - you need the files that accompany it:
`Form1.cs`, `Form1.designer.cs` and maybe some resource files such as `Form1.resx`.
I suggest going through the basics before attempting complicated code.